# PHP checkboxes and $_GET array variables

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a bad issue and already lost 2 days with it. I'm trying to filter a result set with checkboxes and $_GET method but for some reason is nbot working. The $_GET variable for checkbox name is always one string and not array.

I have :

```
<form action="" method="get">

GET<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="A" />Acorn Building<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="B" />Brown Hall<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="C" />Carnegie Complex<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="D" />Drake Commons<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="E" />Elliot House

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

After submit I have this in $_GET :

```
Array ( [page] => xxxx[stype] => xx [entrant] => xxx [formDoor1[]] => C [formSubmit] => Submit )
```

after I've checked the first 3 checkboxes ( the $_GET has only one value - the last one checked  and is not an array.

NOTE: the same form with $_POST form is working fine .

Any help is appreciated as I'm going crazy with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<form action="" method="get">

GET<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[A]"/>Acorn Building<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[B]"/>Brown Hall<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[C]"/>Carnegie Complex<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[D]"/>Drake Commons<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[E]"/>Elliot House

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 <form action="" method="get">

 GET<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="A" />Acorn Building<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="B" />Brown Hall<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="C" />Carnegie Complex<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="D" />Drake Commons<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor1[]" value="E" />Elliot House

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['formDoor1'])) {

//Loop through  array to fetch individual value so that we can use them
  echo "<h2> You have selected: </h2>";
  foreach($_POST['formDoor1'] as $formDoor1) {
  echo "<p>".$formDoor1 ."</p>"; //Print all the values

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the checkbox values in GET method as like POST.

Try this one:

```
$formDoor1 = isset($_GET['formDoor1']) && is_array($_GET['formDoor1']) ? $_GET['formDoor1'] : false;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($formDoor1);
```